# PySpark (AWS Glue) spill when reading large CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

In AWS Glue (PySpark) I'm reading a 29GB CSV file from S3 then repartitioning to 204 partitions and finally writing out to S3. The log shows that a single executor is processing the entire 29GB and spilling a huge amount of data to disk. To me this seems like Spark is using a single executor to first read the entire CSV to its memory then spilling the rest to disk, then streaming the data into each partition across the executors. Is this correct? I was under the impression that a splittable format such as CSV could be read more efficiently in chunks without spill. Is the only way to avoid the single-executor read to break up the input CSV into smaller files before reading? Also, why are the 101GB disk and 40GB spill larger than the input size of 29GB? I'm generally just trying to understand how the data transfer is happening with respect to executors/partitions.

[Spark UI FileScan DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRDc9.png)

[Spark UI FileScan Executor Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkCdi.png)

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import time
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session


df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header',True)\
                            .option('multiline',True)\
                            .option("escape", "\"")\
                            .option("delimiter", ",")\
                            .load(f's3://bucket/folder')

df = df.repartition(numPartitions=204)


db = 'athena-db-name'
path = 's3://target_bucket/target_folder'
table = 'target_table_name'
folder = table.replace('_','-')
target_path = path + folder


df.write.saveAsTable(f"`{db}`.{table}", format='parquet', mode='overwrite', path=target_path)
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem.  I wonder if your file is compressed using .gz?   If so, I've read some other posts stating that the solution may be to deflate and recompress into a compression type that is splittable: